# How to restore only one file to cloned git repo?

Tags: git, github, repository

So I have a cloned repo on the production server. I accidentally removed a file from the production server and I thought doing a "git pull" would restore that file, i.e. copy the last version of the repo. Now I see that is doesn't, so I wonder how do I get this single file back in its proper place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout <file-name>`

Check out this git ready page for more details
http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/11/reverting-files.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `git status`. This will show you pretty much everything you can do with your changed/new/deleted files.

In case you deleted a file it will tell you how exactly you can use `git checkout` to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that easy huh?!

git checkout [path/to/file]

=)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset --hard` to undo all the changes done. First, it's always worth noting that `git reset --hard` is a potentially dangerous command, since it throws away all your uncommitted changes. For safety, you should always check that the output of `git status` is clean (i.e. empty) before using it.